# Interfaces can be of type nil but that doesn't mean they are nil?

Tags: go, pointers, interface, null

I wrote a bit of code that in effect does this:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type SomeInterface interface {
    Retrieve(identifier string)
}

type SomeStruct struct {}

func (r SomeStruct) Retrieve(identifier string) {
    fmt.Println("identifier ", identifier)
}

type Handler struct {
    Name string
    SomeObject SomeInterface
}

func main() {
    var someStruct *SomeStruct
    var h = Handler{
        Name: "helo",
        SomeObject: someStruct,
    }
    fmt.Printf("before %+v\r\n", h.SomeObject)
    if h.SomeObject == nil {
        fmt.Printf("during %+v\r\n", h.SomeObject)
    }
    fmt.Printf("after %+v\r\n", h.SomeObject)
}
```

Please can someone explain to me why the output of the above is:

```
before <nil>
after <nil>
```

I've been reading about interfaces of type `nil` but in this case I have assigned the interface to a pointer that hasn't been assigned so I would have thought that the interface `== nil` and I would see `during <nil>` - alas it is not the case.

Comment: Note that `nil` is *not* a type, it is a predeclared identifier that represents the uninitialized, ["zero" value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value), of some types, like interfaces for example. So saying something like "interface of type nil" is just not right.

Comment: See the Go FAQ.

Comment: No, interfaces _cannot_ be of type `nil`. Nil is not a type.

Comment: https://golang.org/doc/faq#nil_error

Answer (score 2):

An interface value is a simple data structure with two parts, a type and an underlying value. So, the interface value itself can be `nil`, or the interface value can exist but the underlying value can be `nil`. For example:

```
var x interface{} = nil // x is nil
var y interface{} = (interface{})(nil) // y is a interface{}, which *contains* nil
```

This is in some ways conceptually similar to this difference:

```
var x []*int = nil // x is nil
var y []*int = []*int{nil} // y is a []*int, which *contains* nil
```

`fmt.Printf` obscures the difference in the case of an interface because of the way it formats the output; you could see the difference more clearly using reflection if you wanted to.

Answer (score 1):

SomeObject is not nil, it just points to SomeStruct which is nil.

i think the confusion is fmt.Printf prints `<nil>` for this case cuz it's following the pointer and that end result is nil.

Comment: I guess what they're asking is, "if it is not nil, when _what actually is it_ (in terms of memory layout, for example)?"

Comment: it's a pointer to a memory address. The value AT that memory address happens to be nil.

Answer (score 1):

In Go, a variable referring to an implementer of some interface can have many types. It can be of type `<nil>` (yes, `nil` can describe a type as well as a value), it can be the type of one of its implementers, or it can be the type of a pointer to one of its implementers. By default, a variable referring to an interface is of type `nil`. Once you've assigned something to it (other than `nil` itself), it will then take on the type of the thing you've assigned to it (again, either the type of one of its implementers, or a pointer to one of those types).

You can print the type of an interface variable with `%T`, and its value with %v:

```
func main() {
    var i SomeInterface
    fmt.Printf("%T, %v\n", i, i) // Prints <nil>, <nil>
    
    var someStruct SomeStruct
    i = someStruct
    fmt.Printf("%T, %v\n", i, i) // Prints main.SomeStruct, {}
    
    var someStructPtr *SomeStruct
    i = someStructPtr
    fmt.Printf("%T, %v\n", i, i) // Prints *main.SomeStruct, <nil>
}
```

Now, whenever you compare `h.SomeObject == nil`, the comparison will only be evaluated as true if both the types *and* values of the two operands match. In your case, the value of `h.SomeObject` is clearly `<nil>` (after all, the value of `someStruct` is surely `<nil>`, and you store its value in `h.SomeObject`). The type of `h.SomeObject`, based on what I just explaind, must be `*SomeStruct`. The value of `nil` is obviously `<nil>`.

However, what is the *type* of `nil`?

Well, `nil` can take on many types, and the compiler has to decide what type it should take on for each usage. When it comes to comparisons and assignments, it simply takes on the type of the thing it is being compared to or assigned to. For instance, if you are comparing an integer pointer to `nil`, then the `nil` in such a case will be of type `*int`.

But all of this has to be decided at *compile time*, and a variable referring to an interface can change types during *runtime*. So when you compare a variable referring to an interface to `nil`, what type does the compiler give to the `nil` operand in such a case? Well, it gives it the only *sensible* type, `<nil>`.

For a final example, consider the following code:

```
func main() {
    var p *SomeStruct = nil // = nil is optional; pointers default to nil
    var i SomeInterface = p
    printf("%t\n", p == nil) // Prints true
    printf("%t\n", p == i) // Prints true
    printf("%t\n", i == nil) // Prints false
}
```

`p == nil` is true, since `p` is of type `*SomeStruct` with value `<nil>`, and `nil` (in this case) is also of type `*SomeStruct` with value `<nil>`.

`p == i` is true, since `i` is *also* of type `*SomeStruct` with value `<nil>` (it is simply storing the type and value of `p`).

However, `i == nil` is false, because `nil`, in this case, takes on the type `<nil>` rather than `*SomeStruct`.

The solution around this problem is simply to *never* store something of value `<nil>` in an interface-referring variable, except for `nil` itself. That way, whenever the value of the interface-referring variable is `<nil>`, its type will also be `<nil>`, and comparisons against `nil` will work as expected. For this reason, you often see code that looks like this:

```
if p == nil {
    i = nil
} else {
    i = p
}
```

Comment: P.S. there's a great article explaining this in further detail here: https://www.calhoun.io/when-nil-isnt-equal-to-nil/